# How to change text of a paragraph when submit button is clicked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a uni assignment in which we have to create a simple form and when the Submit button is clicked a paragraph with some text should appear underneath the form.

The problem is that when I click Submit the text only appears for a brief second.
How can I make it stay after the Submit button is clicked and the form is submited?

Here is the code.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form2_css.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Mask and IPv4</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Mask and IPv4</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <ul>
                        <td class="firstCol"><label for="ipAdress"><li>IP Adress</li></label></td>
                    </ul>
                    <td><input value="ipAdress1" type="number" id="ipAdress1" name="ipAdress1" min ="1" max="999"></td>  
                    <td><input value="ipAdress2" type="number" id="ipAdress2" name="ipAdress2" min ="1" max="999"></td>
                    <td><input value="ipAdress3" type="number" id="ipAdress3" name="ipAdress3" min ="1" max="999"></td>
                    <td><input value="ipAdress4" type="number" id="ipAdress4" name="ipAdress4" min ="1" max="999"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <ul>
                        <td class="firstCol"><label for="mask"><li>Network Mask</li></label></td>
                    </ul>
                    <td><input value="mask1" type="number" id="mask1" name="mask1" min ="1" max="999"></td>
                    <td><input value="mask2" type="number" id="mask2" name="mask2" min ="1" max="999"></td>
                    <td><input value="mask3" type="number" id="mask3" name="mask3" min ="1" max="999"></td>
                    <td><input value="mask4" type="number" id="mask4" name="mask4" min ="1" max="999"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="submitButton" type="submit" form="form1" onclick="printToScreen()">Submit</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="resetButton" type="reset" form="form1">Reset</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p id="binaryPrint"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function printToScreen() {
    document.getElementById("binaryPrint").innerHTML = "test!";
}
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

body {
    background-color: rgb(174, 216, 91);
}

fieldset {
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
    
}

legend, label {
    font-size: 20px;
}

input {
    size: 50%;
} 

.firstCol {
    padding-right: 100px;
}

button {
    padding: 3px
}
```

Comment: Because you have a `type="submit"` button

Comment: look it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803850/javascript-change-paragraph-text-on-each-button-click

Answer (score 1):

The reason for such behaviour is that you're have `button type="submit"`. The default action when you click it is form submit. You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit

To prevent that you can use `type="button"` instead and then handle the form submission inside the `printToScreen` function.

Comment: I changed the type="button" and after some google searches, I added document.getElementById("form1").submit(); inside the printToScreen() function, but it does the same...The text only appears for a brief moment and then disappears again.

Comment: Yes, that's because you're submitting the form inside the printToScreen() function. I'm not sure what do you want to achieve here? If you want to send some request (with form data) on submit and don't want to reload the page then you can use fetch API for example.